# A very seldom black thick lines flashing on monitor. Its a new pc. I also hear statics on my headphones when it happens

Tags: power-supply, power

So I have a new pc. And i have it for almost 1 month. And im just concerned about the black thin lines/thick lines flashes.
It only happens for like 2-3seconds, I also hear statics on my headphone when it happens.
It only happend 5-6 times the whole month so its very seldom but i wanna know the problem so I know if I will use my warranty.
So i wanna ask if someone has any idea of the exact problem

Comment: Sounds very much like electronic interference. Best thing you can do for now is re-route your cables so they don't all overlap each other, try and keep power cables away from video and audio cables.

Comment: @spikey_richie I was thinking maybe its the electricity of the house since I think the power here is unstable

Comment: In which case, you might want to invest in a surge protector (VERY soon) and/or a UPS with mains power conditioning.

Comment: Okay thankyou. Ill go and buy a ups and observe it again.

Comment: Also.. keep in mind.. as long as the UPS can condition your power.. it is good enough.  How LONG you can run on the UPS is a different thing.